# How to handle Index Error in Tuple Exception in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, tuples, except, index-error

So I have the follwowing Code:

```
  try: 
    pygame.mixer.music.load(songs[index])
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    check_event()
except:
    ("IndexError: tuple index out of range")
    messagebox.showinfo("error","an Error occured")
```

And I want, that if the tuple index is out of range, that it shows you a Messagebox. I have searched for solutions in the internet, and they all say the same, but it doesn't work for me. I hope you can help me.

Edit:

Declaration of songs:

```
songs = list(filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir=r'C:\Users\kevin\Music'))
songs_string = str(songs)
```

And here my new Code:

```
index_musiclist_end = len(songs)
index_musiclist_end = index_musiclist_end +1
if index <= index_musiclist_end: 
    pygame.mixer.music.load(songs[index])
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    next_one = songlist.curselection()
    next_one = next_one[0]+1
    songlist.selection_clear(0,END)
    songlist.activate(next_one)
    songlist.select_set(next_one,last=None)
    check_event()
else :
    messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Index out of Range")
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: What do I have to write for the except statement, so that it will show me a message box when the error occurs ?

Comment: Your `try/except` should catch most of the exceptions including index error.  So the message box should be shown in this case.

Comment: Why do you add one to `index_musiclist_end`? Also the checking should be `if 0 <= index < index_musiclist_end:` instead.  Then if `index` is not within the range, the message box should be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
try:
    pygame.mixer.music.load(songs[index])
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    check_event()
except IndexError as e: # tuple index out of range
    messagebox.showinfo("Error",e)
```

Edit:

```
# Assuming songs is a tuple
def index_exists(songs, index):
    try:
        songs[index]
    except IndexError:
        return False
    return True
if index_exists(songs, index):
    pygame.mixer.music.load(songs[index])
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    check_event()
else:
    messagebox.showinfo("Error","An error occured.")
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. It only shows me the error in the Console as before.

Comment: Well, I don't know, it just gives me more errors. I will pause this right now, and do this later. But thank you for your help.

Comment: Okay. Please inform about the errors when you can.

Comment: So I have tried a new solution (See below edit), but it doesn't work, it just doesn't show me the message box.